# What is the POSIX-defined buffering on a file opened after closing stdout?

Tags: c, posix, file-descriptor, multiprocess

Say I have the following code:

```c
close(1);
int fd = open("temp.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
if (fork() == 0)
    printf("Message from A\n");
printf("Message from B\n");
```

I am aware that `stdout` is line-buffered, and I've noticed that, at least on my system, this works as one would expect.

i.e.

The contents of *temp.txt* are:

```
Message from B
Message from A
Message from B
```

However, what is the behavior defined by POSIX for the above code? Is line-buffering preserved for file descriptor 1 (even after a `close()`)? Is it undefined? Something else? I am assuming that the `open()` command will always use file descriptor 1 for *temp.txt* in the above code.

Additionally, would it be possible, say, for only part of `"Message from A\n"` or `"Message from B\n"` to be written to the buffer associated with file descriptor 1 before the CPU loaded the other process and overwrote the partial message that was just written?

e.g.

Is it possible that the parent parent process only manages to write "Message" to the buffer before it gets interrupted by the child, resulting in the following content in *temp.txt* (or something similar):

```
Message from A
 from B
Message from B
```

**NOTE:**

The code above is what was given to me in an assignment I have for one of my classes. I understand that it is better to open a file and then call `dup2()`, rather than closing file descriptor 1, and then opening the file.

Comment: About second part, POSIX printf is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX doesn't specify C's buffering, it's specified by the C standard.

The default buffering of a the standard input and output streams is determined when the program starts. Changing the FD associated with the stream has no effect on this. If `stdout` was initially associated with a terminal, it will be line-buffered, and opening a file on FD 1 doesn't change this, so it's still line-buffered when writing to the file.

Comment: Why then does this [test program](https://pastebin.com/xVGngecH) result in only 100 lines being printed to _temp.txt_, rather than 1000 lines?

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay, but the code, which I included above in my question, doesn't have this issue. Wouldn't the parent also write to the same position in the file? How else would it know at which point its children wrote?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, I get 1000 lines in temp.txt. Are you sure you're running the program with stdout connected to a terminal?

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it from the terminal, so stdout initially should be connected to the terminal. However, the program closes stdout and opens a new file, which takes the lowest FD, which should be 1. Then it proceeds to fork 9 child processes, all of which write 100 lines to the file. However, at least when I run the program on my machine (`uname -r => 4.19.69-1-MANJARO`), only 100 lines are written, rather than the expected 1000.

Comment: I understand the question, I just can't reproduce it. I ran it on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Actually, I just reproduced it on Debian. I can't explain it.

Answer (score 2):

If standard output is terminal, it is line buffered. If its a file, it does not need to be. It depends on platform/implementation.
In your second example program, you are not seeing 1000 lines because you are terminating child processes with `_exit`.

```
if (pid == 0)
{

    _exit(0);
}
```

Instead you should be using exit. The difference is exit does stuff such as closing files and flushing streams, then calls _exit to perform actual termination. If you terminate child processes with regular exit (or just let them terminate at the end of main regularly), their output should be flushed into file as well.

Update: Accordingly, whether [_exit](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html) flushes streams or not is implementation defined, this is probably the reason Barmar encountered different results with Mac and Linux, but exit always flushes. Quote from the _exit link:

> Whether open streams are closed (without flushing) is
>   implementation-defined

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I upvoted you, but I accepted Barmar's answer, since it was the answer to my original question.

Comment: @jinscoe123 I think closing standard output and reopening a file on FD 1 changed output from being line-buffered to being not. But I do not have any sources on this.